# how to limit the input integer

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that will determine the password if its valid or not! My problem is what code i need to use to limit the input integer of the user.

here is the requirement for the password

•   A password must have at least eight characters.

•   A password consists of only letters, digits and underscore.

•   **A password must contain at least two digits numbers.**

```
def password():
    password = input ('Please Type your Password: ')

    _ = "_"

    if len(password) <=7 or set('[~!@#$%^&*()+{}":;\']+$').intersection(password) <=1:
        print ("You Enter a Invalid Password")

    else:
        len(password)>=8 and password.lower()== password and password.upper()==password and password.isalnum()==password and set(_).intersection(password)
        print ("You Enter a Valid Password")

password()
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your user is inputting an integer. What's the logic behind your code? Note that  `isalnum` returns a `bool` so `password.isalnum() == password` will always be false because a `bool` is different from a string. Also that whole line after the `else` is useless.

Comment: I`m new in python sir can you help me correct it??

Comment: I can't help you if I can't understand what you are asking. "The maximum integer is 2 integers" doesn't make any sense. Explain *which* passwords you want to validate.